# Prevent task deletion by anyone other than task creator

Tags: apex, trigger, validation, tasks

I need to create a trigger that will prevent the deletion of a task by anyone other than the creator.  I don't know about writing code so I'm hoping someone can help me out with this.  It would be an assigned task on a custom object called Closings if that makes any difference.
Help!?

```
trigger NoDeleteonAssignedTask on Task (before delete) {
String ProfileId = UserInfo.getProfileId();String UserID = Userinfo.getUserId(); 
List<Profile> profiles=[select id from Profile where name='PB Administrator'];

if (1!=profiles.size())
{
   // unable to get the profiles - handle error
}
else
{

for (Task a : Trigger.old)      

IF(a.IsAssigned__c==True &&(UserID!=a.CreatedbyID && (profileId!=profiles[0].id )))
{
     Apexpages.addMessage(new Apexpages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'deletetaskerror'));

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but typically questions asking for a solution without demonstrating an attempt are not particularly well received. Please visit the [help] and read [ask]. Welcome to SFSE!

Comment: Thank you for letting me know Adrian.  I will revise to show attempts.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Any luck here @JenB?

Comment: @Adrian Larson I'm trying but I'm not a developer so this is requiring a great deal of reading and piecing together for me.  The only thing I'm stuck on is having it display a VF page instead of Custom Label.  This is my code.

Comment: You need to use the `addError` method, not `ApexPages.addMessage`...

Answer (score 5):

You need to write a `delete` trigger.

- Validations should happen `before delete`.
- You can get the Id of the running user via `UserInfo.getUserId()`.
- You can compare the `CreatedById` to the running user Id.
- You can validate in an `Apex Trigger` using the `SObject.addError` method.
- I recommend implementing a handler pattern.
- I recommend putting the error message in a `Custom Label`.
- Make sure you stick to One Trigger Per Object.

Comment: Enabler...lol....

Comment: Alright @Eric, I made my advice *very generic* so that it's not spoon-feeding.

Comment: I will post what I come up with.  This approach is VERY MUCH appreciated as I want to learn these things but am overwhelmed with understanding the different approaches to automatically handling the data.  Don't let them bust your chops - you are TEACHING me!